FCGI errors when running an HTTP Git server through Nginx on Ubuntu
I am trying to set up an HTTP Git server on an Ubuntu VPS with an Nginx server serving an existing website (I want to use Git over HTTP in order to be compatible with isomorphic-git). I followed this tutorial here: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-git-server-installation/ and the repo itself is /var/www/html/gitrepo/myrepo.git/
I can't seem to get rid of this error whenever I try to actually use the git server:
[error] 26141#26141: *23 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?" while reading response header from upstream, client: <IP Address>, server: _, request: "GET /git/myrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: "<Website>"

At some point I booted up an Ubuntu VM locally and went through all the same steps and was finally able to run git requests successfully on that VM. Then I looked at the nginx error logs anyway and saw this:
[error] 4066#4066: *52 user "<User I set in htpasswd file>": password mismatch, client: 10.0.2.2, server: _, request: "GET /git/myrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:3000"

Yet I was able to clone, push, and pull just fine?
What's more, just creating a quick FCGI script also failed for the same reason ("Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME..." etc) on both the VM and the VPS:
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "FastCGI test is working."

Here's what I've got both in my VM and VPS in /etc/nginx/sites-available/mywebsite.conf, after a few rounds of simplifying and (attempted) sanity checking.
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html;

    location /fcgitest {
        # This does not work on either the VM or VPS and returns a 403 every time
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/test.fcgi;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }

    location /hello {
        # This works
        return 200 "Hello, World!";
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        add_header Content-Length 13;
    }

    location ~ ^/git(/.*) {
        # This works(?) on the VM, not on the VPS
        root /var/www/html/gitrepo;
        client_max_body_size 0;

        auth_basic "Git Login";
        auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/html/gitrepo/htpasswd";

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /usr/lib/git-core;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /git;
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/html/gitrepo;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}

This feels like something that should be very straightforward to set up.
